# Excel VBA-How to Extract Specific Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple "Rooms" in an excel spread sheet and would like to extract the Room, Name, Laptops, Make and Manager while excluding Faculty and Budget.

```
   Room 1#  |
   Name     |   Office2
            |
   Laptops  |   22
            |
   Make     |   Mac
            |
   People   |   17
            |
   Faculty  |   Accounts
            |
   Manager  |   John
            |
   Budget   |  xxxxx
            |
   Room 2#  |
            |
   Name     |   Office3
            |
   Laptops  |   22
            |
   Make     |   HP
            |
   People   |   20
            |
   Faculty  |   Marketimg
            |
   Manager  |   Jeff
            |
   Budget   |  xxxxx
```

I am trying to extract all the data I require by modifying the following code but am having difficulty in getting the data in the same order as it is in the sample.

```
Sub CopyManager()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = "Manager" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If there is anything useful in that external link, please include it in the question itself.  Most users won't follow links to potentially virus-infected files.  (Or, at least, they **shouldn't**.)  And links get broken, which make them useless for people searching for solutions in the future.

Comment: do you want to copy the value and the format of the cell, or do you want to copy cells having specific format?

Comment: What formats are not being transferred?  Copy should transfer almost all that are attached to those cells.

Comment: I would like to copy the cells having a specific format and order. Thank you for your feedback @YowE3K I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your Source sheet has a first riw for headers, you could use AutoFilter() method to filter only relevant records and paste them in one shot:

```
Sub CopyManager()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim valsArray As Variant

    valsArray = Array("Room*", "Name", "Laptops", "Make","Manager") '<--| define your values to be filtered on Source sheet column A
    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With Source  '<--| reference Source sheet
        With .Range("A1:A1000")  '<--| reference its range from A1 to A1000
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= valsArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues  '<--| filter referenced range on its first column with values stored in valsArray
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than 
                .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 2).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("A1") '<--|copy filtered cells skipping headers and paste in target sheet from cell A1
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode= False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @smurf, did you get through it?

Comment: This is working very well thank you! Is there anyway I can change the code in order to have a few blank rows after each room?

Comment: Hi @user3598756 what would be the best way to allow for spacing between each copied row?

Comment: You could loop backwards through pasted rows with step -2 and insert a row. Or you could use a "helper" column where to put row indexes (pasted rows: from 1 onwards stepping 2; as many rows below pasted ones: from 2 onwards stepping 2) and then sort by it

Answer (score 1):

The following change to your code should do it:

```
Sub CopyManager()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For r = 1 To 1000   ' Do 1000 rows
        Select Case Left(Trim(Source.Cells(r, 1).Value), 4)
            Case "Mana", _
                 "Make", _
                 "Room", _
                 "Name", _
                 "Lapt"
                Source.Rows(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I use a `Select Case` statement to save having to write a slightly longer `If` statement, and I just look at the first 4 characters of column A so that it handles `Room x#` type cells.

---

If you needed blank rows after most of the values (except for "Room"), I would suggest a slight rework of my code above:

```
Sub CopyManager()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For r = 1 To 1000   ' Do 1000 rows
        Select Case Left(Trim(Source.Cells(r, 1).Value), 4)
            Case "Mana", _
                 "Make", _
                 "Name", _
                 "Lapt"
                Source.Rows(r & ":" & (j + 1)).Copy Target.Rows(j & ":" & (j + 1))
                'or, if the "|" in your example is just signifying a new column, use the simpler
                Source.Rows(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)

                j = j + 2
            Case "Room"
                Source.Rows(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @YowE3K your answer has also provided to be very useful! My apologies in the delay in getting back to you.